# Reverse engineering from an APK file to a project by MAC

Tags: android

I accidentally erased my project from Eclipse, and all I have left is the APK file which I transferred to my phone. Is there a way to reverse the process of exporting an application to the .apk file, so I can get my project back? by using MacOS X ?

Comment: no , I need for MAc , that you mention it for windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this](http://pof.eslack.org/2011/02/18/from-apk-to-readable-java-source-code-in-3-easy-steps/). You can unzip the classes.dex from your apk file on the mac, and dex2jar should work on a mac as well.

The last part, jd, is a windows program, but they have an online demo [on their project site](http://jd.benow.ca/) - click "live demo" in the header, then drag and drop your jar file on the `input files` box.

**Edit**
I just noticed there are download links for jd on mac as well, so you don't need to use the online version. You can even use the jd for eclipse plugin on a mac.